# Visual Studio 2017: CL.exe exited with code -1073741515

Tags: c, visual-studio

I recently installed VS community. When I did so, I choose "desktop development with c++". I also check "cli/c++ support".

I tried to run simple c program with "hello world", but this error appears. Nothing i found helped me.

Please help me, thank you.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz2N2.jpg)

Comment: Please double-click on the error, then go to the Output tab and see whether additional information is available as to what exactly failed.

Comment: do not post screen shots,  Post the actual text (copy and paste works well)

Comment: the screen shot fails to post the actual code.  How do you expect us to determine the cause of the error when the code that caused the error is not posted

Comment: sorry guys, im new here. here is the copy/paste:  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515. Project1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 380

Comment: and here is the part it takes me: https://pastebin.com/8sLUMdFC

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Visual Studio. Most probably it's damaged. Also it's possible that your hardware is failed.